# Can we add two flatlists to a section list?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two flatlists which are being created by [this](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist) library. And I want to swapping of cells between the two sections. How can this be done? Or is there any other library which allows this?

I have also tried using https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list/

Comment: try searching a library similar to react-dnd, but this question is incomplete, if you have tried anything so far you can share,

Comment: My search has hit a dead end so I was looking to add two flatlists to a section list. But that wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there any other library which allows this?

I've used ReactDND with success before. You can certainly drag between sorted lists in ReactDND but it will take a bit of work. See here for examples:

http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/sortable/simple

http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/examples/dustbin/multiple-targets

Comment: Thankyou very much!! Will definitely check it out.

Comment: Happy to help @vedantbajaj!

Comment: Hi I tried to used it but it seems that it is for React JS and not React-Native. I couldn't integrate it.

Comment: I even found react-beautiful-dnd but it's the same thing